# isLong() method not working

Tags: java

I have been trying to figure out why this code hasn't worked for hours, and I am fairly new to ArrayList methods. Basically, the `isLong` method is not working and I am unsure why. The compiler is saying  "Cannot find method - method isLong".

ERROR:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class BookCollection
{
    private ArrayList<Book> bookList;
    public BookCollection() throws Exception
    {
        bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
        String firstLine, isbnI, authorI, areaI;
        int lengthI;
        Book book;
        Scanner FILE, fileScan;
        fileScan = new Scanner(new File("Books.txt"));
            while (fileScan.hasNext())
            {
              firstLine = fileScan.nextLine();
              FILE = new Scanner(firstLine);
              isbnI = FILE.next();
              authorI = FILE.next();
              areaI = FILE.next();
              lengthI = FILE.nextInt();
              book = new Book(isbnI, authorI, areaI, lengthI);
              bookList.add(book);
            }
    }
    public void displayLongBooks()
    {
      System.out.println("LONG BOOKS\n\n");
      for(int i = 0; i < bookList.size(); i++)
      {
        if (bookList.get(i).isLong())
        {
          return System.out.println(bookList.get(i)+"\n");
        }
      }
    }
    void displayBooksFromAuthor(String Author)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < bookList.size(); i++)
      {
        if (bookList.get(i).author.equals(Author))
          System.out.println(bookList.get(i));
      }
    }
    void displayBooksFromArea(String Area)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < bookList.size(); i++)
      {
        if (bookList.get(i).area.equals(Area))
          System.out.println(bookList.get(i));
      }
    }
    Book longestBook()
    {
        int maxId = 0;
        int currMax = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < bookList.size(); i++)
        {
          Book currBook = bookList.get(i);
          if(currBook.getLength() > currMax)
          {
            currMax = currBook.getLength();
            maxIdx = i;
          }
        }
        return bookList.get(maxIdx);
    }

}
`
```

isLong method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Book
{
  String isbn, author, area;
  int length;

  public Book(String isbn, String author, String area, int length)
  {
      this.isbn = isbn;
      this.author = author;
      this.area = area;
      this.length = length;
  }

  boolean islong()
  {
      if(length >= 400)
        return true;
      else
        return false;
  }

 String toString()
  {
     String s;
     S = "[BOOK ISBN: " + this.isbn + ", AUTHOR: " + this.author + ", AREA: " + this.area + ", PAGES: " + this.length + "]\n";
     return s;
  }
 public String getIsbn()
 {
   return this.isbn;
 }

 public String getAuthor()
 {
    return this.author;
 }

 public String getArea()
 {
    return this.area;
 }

 public int getLength()
 {
    return this.length;
 }


}
`
```

main method:

```
`
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestBookCollection
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    BookCollection testBooks = new BookCollection();

    System.out.println(testBooks);
    System.out.println();
    testBooks.displayLongBooks();
    System.out.println("\nChoose an author: ");
    String author = scan.next();
    testBooks.displayBooksFromAuthor(author);
    System.out.println("\nChoose an area: ");
    String area = scan.next();
    testBooks.displayBooksFromArea(area);
  }
}
`
```

Comment: Your method is called islong... there's no L there.

Comment: Java identifiers are case-sensitive: you call `isLong` but you declared `islong`.

Comment: Also note: Using a boolean expression to select true/false is totally redundant - use the expression directly: "return length >= 400;"

Comment: Wow.. thank you so much, I cant believe I didn't realize that...

Answer (score 1):

You declared the method as `islong` instead of as `isLong`.